# C# POST data contains slashes /\

Tags: c#, post

Okay so I have my post data, and its example like this.

```
String postData = "frc":"AH02kYryGWhATiVGkuFBnnn9Dd1rVBYHjR2iqUFQRESla74sdM4hseFkBPtxFH80M7\/\/VNsp8XEsU93wJnf\/A6s+EO3YvkmNoMnlIVoeFbUuwOnnnaVi3NLC1W1h8Ym\/0TlXMJJGkibKK0BA39SRAlsM8b1PmQNDWbfaX5rIMNIIxWB0vXfj9Bz\/16eB9ufb4jVX9zlyuNoM6hTY00E6LnTRXyEwOWmtXJppQDa+fhFgvXaVWeSfW\/uwlth8agSt4TjgDEPvLkXFuslpSO3FL4m2K41ovAeH\/o5mquaIsIZ\/Mfo3zbCXPc1f6ti7JEJNvi6b1WPkNK49EbTPRiROrhDpdQqjo9fEBgK\/v7LvM7WECdObQPJp\/KQ="}}";
String html = http.postRequest("https://examplesite.com/auth/", postData, frc);
```

So here is the part I'm stuck on, it's not forming correct with the /\ in the post data how would I make my post data correct with those there?

As shown in the image, they are coming up as errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Q9UE.png)

Comment: Please include the code you are using to generate the post data. We can't tell you how to fix what currently have if you don't show us what you currently have.

Comment: It looks like a GET request to me. You need to encode your data using javascript urlencode methods

Comment: I've updated my post with more information so it's more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is backslashes are used to represent special characters like tab `\t`, if you have them in your string you must do two slashes to fix them or use a string literal with `@` to turn off the escaping. Also you need to fix the `":"` and the `KQ="}}` you have in the string, the extra quotes will break the string. You can fix it either by escaping them with a `\` or by using two `"` in a row when doing a string literal.

With escaping

```
String postData = "frc\":\"AH02kYryGWhATiVGkuFBnnn9Dd1rVBYHjR2iqUFQRESla74sdM4hseFkBPtxFH80M7\\/\\/VNsp8XEsU93wJnf\\/A6s+EO3YvkmNoMnlIVoeFbUuwOnnnaVi3NLC1W1h8Ym\\/0TlXMJJGkibKK0BA39SRAlsM8b1PmQNDWbfaX5rIMNIIxWB0vXfj9Bz\\/16eB9ufb4jVX9zlyuNoM6hTY00E6LnTRXyEwOWmtXJppQDa+fhFgvXaVWeSfW\\/uwlth8agSt4TjgDEPvLkXFuslpSO3FL4m2K41ovAeH\\/o5mquaIsIZ\\/Mfo3zbCXPc1f6ti7JEJNvi6b1WPkNK49EbTPRiROrhDpdQqjo9fEBgK\\/v7LvM7WECdObQPJp\\/KQ=\"}}";
```

Notice i changed `":"` to `\":\"` and the `KQ="}}` to `KQ=\"}}` and every place there was a `\` i made it `\\`

With a string literal

```
String postData = @"frc"":""AH02kYryGWhATiVGkuFBnnn9Dd1rVBYHjR2iqUFQRESla74sdM4hseFkBPtxFH80M7\/\/VNsp8XEsU93wJnf\/A6s+EO3YvkmNoMnlIVoeFbUuwOnnnaVi3NLC1W1h8Ym\/0TlXMJJGkibKK0BA39SRAlsM8b1PmQNDWbfaX5rIMNIIxWB0vXfj9Bz\/16eB9ufb4jVX9zlyuNoM6hTY00E6LnTRXyEwOWmtXJppQDa+fhFgvXaVWeSfW\/uwlth8agSt4TjgDEPvLkXFuslpSO3FL4m2K41ovAeH\/o5mquaIsIZ\/Mfo3zbCXPc1f6ti7JEJNvi6b1WPkNK49EbTPRiROrhDpdQqjo9fEBgK\/v7LvM7WECdObQPJp\/KQ=""}}";
```

Here I added  a `@` to the front then repaced every `"` with `""`.